# What is the correct placement of portato marks in relation to phrase marks?

Tags: notation, engraving, musescore

I'm engraving an orchestral score, using Musescore. The following two bars, in the oboe part, don't look "right" in terms of engraving aesthetics:

[image: Portato with phrase marks example 2]

Another example, this time in the flute part:

[image: Portato with phrase marks example]

I think the problem is that the portato marks are not vertically aligned and it's visually quite jarring, especially since the notes are stationary.

It may be, however, technically correct, since phrase marks should normally almost touch note heads at their end-points, leaving not enough room for a portato mark which then has to be placed outside.

BTW those are phrase marks, not slurs.

Before I go ahead and try make things prettier, I'd love to know if there is a generally accepted approach to engraving this correctly?

Comment: I uh...totally didn't read this as "potato marks"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best approach it to place the articulation marks close to the notes and raise (or lower) the phrase marks to "connect" the articulations.

[image: phrase marks adjusted to accommodate portato]

Alternatively, you can place the phrase marks opposite from the articulation marks, by the note stems.

[image: phrase marks opposite portato]

Comment: Yes, this is it, this looks really good. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the portato symbol, you could place both staccato dots and tenuto line on each note.
Looks much nicer, and you won't have to adjust any of the spacing:
[image: music fragment with both staccato and tenuto]

Comment: The rightmost staccatos being under the top staff line and the tenutos being above it looks slightly unnerving to me.

Comment: Fair enough, but I find huge gap between the note head and the proper portato symbol irksome.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, really appreciate it, I'm going with &Aaron's answer because the real portato mark just looks a bit cleaner.

Comment: @MichalCihelka  I agree, the real portato symbol does look better than simply combining the staccato and tenuto symbols.  But I still don't like the spacing between the notehead and the symbol.  
Overall I'm not really a fan of either result.